React Native `handleAddEvent Function` Not Called - Issue with `CustomEventModal` and `index.tsx` Integration
I'm developing a scheduling app using React Native. I have implemented a modal that allows users to add events. The issue I'm facing is that the handleAddEvent function, which should be triggered when the user submits the event details, is not being called.
Problem Description
The handleAddEvent function is not being called from CustomEventModal.
handleSave function in CustomEventModal is calling onSave, but the handleAddEvent function is not being triggered.
I confirmed that the handleSave function is executing, but handleAddEvent and the catch block in it are not logging anything.
// app/index.tsx

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Alert, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { ThemedView } from "@/components/ThemedView";
import BottomSheet from "@/components/BottomSheet";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import CalendarComponent from "@/components/CalendarComponent";
import CustomEventModal from "@/components/EventModal";
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
import moment from "moment";
import ActionButtons from "@/components/ActionButtons";
import ChatInput from "@/components/ChatInput";
import {
  getCurrentDate,
  fetchEventsFromFirestore,
  addEventToFirestore,
} from "@/utils/eventUtils";

const { width: SCREEN_WIDTH } = Dimensions.get("window");

interface Props {
  horizontalView?: boolean;
}

interface Event {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  imageURL?: string; // Added image URL property
}

export default function Main(props: Props) {
  const { horizontalView } = props;
  const initialDate = getCurrentDate();

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(initialDate);
  const [events, setEvents] = useState<Record<string, Event[]>>({});
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [bottomSheetVisible, setBottomSheetVisible] = useState(false);

  const [datePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisible] = useState(false);
  const [currentPicker, setCurrentPicker] = useState<"start" | "end" | null>(
    null
  );
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(initialDate);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(initialDate);

  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<
    { text: string; type: "user" | "ai" }[]
  >([]);

  const [eventModalData, setEventModalData] = useState({
    title: "",
    content: "",
    startDate: initialDate,
    endDate: initialDate,
    imageURL: null, // Added image URL
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEvents = async () => {
      const fetchedEvents = await fetchEventsFromFirestore();
      setEvents(fetchedEvents);
    };
    fetchEvents();
  }, []);

  const handleDayLongPress = (day: any) => {
    setSelected(day.dateString);
    setStartDate(day.dateString);
    setEndDate(day.dateString);
    setModalVisible(true);
  };

  const handleAddEvent = async (
    title: string,
    content: string,
    startDate: string,
    endDate: string,
    imageURL: string | null
  ) => {
    console.log("handleAddEvent called with:", {
      title,
      content,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      imageURL,
    });
    if (!title || !content) {
      Alert.alert("Error", "Please enter the title and content.");
      return;
    }

    if (moment(startDate).isAfter(moment(endDate))) {
      Alert.alert("Error", "The start date cannot be later than the end date.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      console.log("Calling addEventToFirestore...");
      await addEventToFirestore(
        title,
        content,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        imageURL,
        events,
        setEvents
      );
      console.log("Event added successfully.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding event to Firestore:", error);
    }

    setModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleAddEventButton = () => {
    setStartDate(selected);
    setEndDate(selected);
    setModalVisible(true);
  };

  const showDatePicker = (pickerType: "start" | "end") => {
    setCurrentPicker(pickerType);
    setDatePickerVisible(true);
  };

  const handleDateConfirm = (event: any, selectedDate: Date | undefined) => {
    if (selectedDate) {
      const formattedDate = moment(selectedDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      if (currentPicker === "start") {
        setStartDate(formattedDate);
      } else if (currentPicker === "end") {
        setEndDate(formattedDate);
      }
    }
    setDatePickerVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <ThemedView style={styles.container}>
        <CalendarComponent
          initialDate={initialDate}
          events={events}
          setEvents={setEvents}
          selected={selected}
          setSelected={setSelected}
          horizontalView={horizontalView}
          onDayLongPress={handleDayLongPress}
        />
        {bottomSheetVisible && (
          <BottomSheet
            selectedDate={selected}
            events={events[selected]}
            events2={events}
            setEvents={setEvents}
            onAddEvent={handleAddEventButton}
            messages={messages}
            setMessages={setMessages}
          />
        )}
        <CustomEventModal
          visible={modalVisible}
          onClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}
          onSave={handleAddEvent}
          initialDate={selected}
          initialData={eventModalData}
          showDatePicker={showDatePicker}
          startDate={startDate}
          endDate={endDate}
        />
        {datePickerVisible && (
          <DateTimePicker
            value={
              currentPicker === "start"
                ? new Date(startDate)
                : new Date(endDate)
            }
            mode="date"
            display="default"
            onChange={handleDateConfirm}
            minimumDate={new Date()} // Minimum selectable date
          />
        )}
        <ChatInput
          input={input}
          setInput={setInput}
          loading={loading}
          setLoading={setLoading}
          setMessages={setMessages}
        />
        <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
          <ActionButtons
            events={events}
            setEvents={setEvents}
            setBottomSheetVisible={setBottomSheetVisible}
            setEventModalVisible={setModalVisible}
            setEventModalData={setEventModalData}
          />
        </View>
      </ThemedView>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    paddingTop: 50,
  },
  bottomBar: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
    height: 80,
    backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#e0e0e0",
  },
});

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  View,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import moment from "moment";

interface EventModalProps {
  visible: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  onSave: (
    title: string,
    content: string,
    startDate: string,
    endDate: string,
    imageURL: string | null
  ) => void;
  initialDate: string;
  initialData: {
    title: string;
    content: string;
    startDate: string;
    endDate: string;
    imageURL?: string;
  };
}

const CustomEventModal: React.FC<EventModalProps> = ({
  visible,
  onClose,
  onSave,
  initialDate,
  initialData,
}) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(initialData.title || "");
  const [content, setContent] = useState(initialData.content || "");
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(initialData.startDate || initialDate);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(initialData.endDate || initialDate);
  const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState(initialData.imageURL || null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (visible) {
      setTitle(initialData.title || "");
      setContent(initialData.content || "");
      setStartDate(initialData.startDate || initialDate);
      setEndDate(initialData.endDate || initialDate);
      setImageURL(initialData.imageURL || null);
    }
  }, [visible, initialData, initialDate]);

  const handleSave = () => {
    if (title.trim() && content.trim()) {
      if (moment(startDate).isAfter(moment(endDate))) {
        Alert.alert("Error", "The start date cannot be later than the end date.");
        return;
      }
      console.log("handleSave called");
      onSave(title, content, startDate, endDate, imageURL);
      clearFields();
      onClose();
    } else {
      Alert.alert("Error", "Please enter the title and content.");
    }
  };

  const clearFields = () => {
    setTitle("");
    setContent("");
    setStartDate(initialDate);
    setEndDate(initialDate);
    setImageURL(null);
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}
      visible={visible}
      onRequestClose={onClose}
    >
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onClose}>
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View style={styles.modalView}>
              <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>Add New Event</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Event Title"
                value={title}
                onChangeText={setTitle}
              />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.cinput}
                placeholder="Event Details"
                value={content}
                onChangeText={setContent}
                multiline
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.dateButton}
                onPress={() => console.log("Start Date Button Pressed")}
              >
                <Text style={styles.dateButtonText}>
                  Start Date: {startDate}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.dateButton}
                onPress={() => console.log("End Date Button Pressed")}
              >
                <Text style={styles.dateButtonText}>
                  End Date: {endDate}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={[styles.button, styles.saveButton]}
                  onPress={handleSave}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SAVE</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={[styles.button, styles.cancelButton]}
                  onPress={() => {
                    clearFields();
                    onClose();
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>CANCEL</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </Modal>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end", // Align at the bottom of the screen
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
  },
  modalView: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20, // Top-left corner rounded
    borderTopRightRadius: 20, // Top-right corner rounded
    padding: 20,
    paddingBottom: 30,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: -2, // Shadow appears below the element
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  modalTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  input: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "#ccc",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9",
  },
  cinput: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 150,
    borderColor: "#ccc",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9",
  },
  dateButton: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#e9ecef",
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  dateButtonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#495057",
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginTop: 20,
    width: "100%",
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 5,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  saveButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#007BFF",
  },
  cancelButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#6c757d",
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default CustomEventModal;

I put tens of log or alert function and what I got is I don't know why but in the hadleSave() <- EventModal.tsx
didn't call onSave()
And when I changed the boolean value const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false); <- index.tsx from false to true, the schedule registration modal appeared at the bottom of the screen as soon as the app was launched. I confirmed that the onSave function was executed and the data was recorded in Firebase just once when I registered the schedule on that modal.
However, after that, when I attempted to register a schedule, it was only displayed on the screen but was not recorded in Firebase.
